# How do you uninstall Dualboot from Windows XP And Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-xp

I just want to uninstall Ubuntu from my computer because it's really, really sluggish. I searched Google for answers, but I couldn't find the perfect solution. I want to uninstall Ubuntu without a Win XP recovery CD. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sluggish(your opinion) . I use debian and have used ubuntu, i don't find it that sluggish.
             
   *To answer your question.*
**Easybcd** is tool that you can use, it's freeware. 
Caution: *Use it properly, you might end up corrupting your system*.

1. Go to your windows, download and install the tool and you can remove GRUB as default bootloader to windows bootloader.
2. Use any disk partition software remove the disk partition that contains ubuntu.
3. You're completely free of ubuntu.

NOTE: Try ubuntu/debian for sometime, you'll think windows is boring.

Comment: No, It's because my computer only has 1 Gb of ram. It's an old computer since 2008. Thank you for your help!